# How to generate two matrices with given (constrained to) column-wise and row-wise correlations in R?

Tags: r, correlation, simulation, matrix, constraint

I would like to generate two matrices `X` and `Y`, of the same dimensions (`n` x `p`), given a row-wise Pearson correlation value, i.e. `cor(X[i,],Y[i,]) = a`. AND, at the same time, with a given column-wise Pearson correlation value, i.e. `cor(X[,i],Y[,i]) = b`. (In both cases, the correlation can be equal for all `i` -as proposed- or different for every`i` as far as it can be set in advance).

Comment: What is the statistical question this is intended to help with?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.